# How to copy keys and values from one object to another without copying the values

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

I have 2 objects

```
json1 = {
    "name": "padd",
    "value": "1",
    "parentName": "",
    "parentValue": "",
    "children": [],
    "canDisplay": true,
    "showRecord": true
}

json2 = {
    "name": "note",
    "value": "1",
    "parentName": "",
    "parentValue": "",
    "children": [{
        "name": "padd",
        "value": "1",
        "parentName": "",
        "parentValue": "",
        "children": [],
        "canDisplay": true,
        "showRecord": true
    }],
    "canDisplay": true,
    "showRecord": true
}
```

The keys which are missing in `json1` should be added from `json2` and also the values of the keys which are matching in `json1` and `json2` should not be replaced from `json2` to `json1`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will scan json2 and add all those properties of json2 to json1, which are missing in json1, while retaining the values of those properties, which json1 already had.

```
for (var prop in json2) {
    if (json1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // move on to next property
        continue;
    }
    json1[prop] = json2[prop];
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2g4tsted/1/)

Comment: the above code is not copying the contents from json2 to json1 and also i wanted to check for speicific keys in the child nodes and copy the values of those specific keys,like `candisplay` key from json2 to json1 and while copying i wanted to change the values also

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Object.keys method, to loop through keys of json1, and if key is not found in json2, set it to a blank string. e.g.

```
var keys1 = Object.keys(json1);
for (var key_i=0; key_i<keys1.length; key_i++) {
  var key = keys1[key_i];
  if (typeof json2[key] === 'undefined') {
    json2[key] = '';
  }
}
```

Edit:

If you want to copy over values from json1 to json2, if not in json2, then change:

```
json2[key] = '';
```

to

```
json2[key] = json1[key];
```

Comment: the children node is not being copied from json2 to json1 and also i wanted just to iterate and copy the values and the keys with the structure intact

Comment: the above code (with edit), should copy any key/value from json1 to json2, only copying if the key from json1 is not in json2.  Is that what you mean?